# How to make interactive objects in Microsoft Word? (dropdown lists, checkboxes)

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, interactive

As I stated in the title, I'm pretty sure there is some feature that can enable me to do that. Here is a document with an example but I don't know how it was implemented:

[image: Microsoft word interactive text input]

So how is that even possible ?

### Note:

I am using Microsoft Word 2010 on Windows 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How is that (displaying a drop down list) even possible?

Those drop down lists in your example are elements of a [form](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-forms-that-users-complete-or-print-in-word-040c5cc1-e309-445b-94ac-542f732c8c8b):

> To create a form in Word that others can fill out, start with a template or document and add content controls. Content controls include things like check boxes, text boxes, date pickers, and drop-down lists. If you’re familiar with databases, these content controls can even be linked to data.

Source: [Create forms that users complete or print in Word - Office Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-forms-that-users-complete-or-print-in-word-040c5cc1-e309-445b-94ac-542f732c8c8b)

Posting full instructions would take too much space for an answer, but you can find full tutorials at:

- [Adding Form Fields to a MS Word Document - SmartWiki](https://wiki.smartsimple.com/wiki/Adding_Form_Fields_to_a_MS_Word_Document),
- [How to Create a Fillable Form in Word | CustomGuide](https://www.customguide.com/word/how-to-create-a-fillable-form-in-word), and
- [How to Create Fillable Forms in Microsoft Word](https://www.itsolutions-inc.com/news-and-training/article/how-to-create-fillable-forms-in-microsoft-word).

These links should get you started.

Comment: I would add Greg Maxey's **Create a Form Using Word Content Controls.** http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/content_control_fillin_form.html